# Maze generation with keys and doors

Tags: algorithm, maze

I've gone through a lot of the common maze generating algorithms but have yet to find something that might be able to help me out here.

I want to create a maze with doors that you can only go through after collecting a key elsewhere in the maze. All keys should be necessary to complete the maze, and you should be able to specify the number of keys that exist in the maze.

Does anyone know anything that could help me out here?

Comment: Generate maze without doors, then generate random locations for doors on the path between start and finish, then pick random locations for keys between start and the applicable door.

Comment: You can generate maze in a grid putting 0's and 1's randomly where 0 can be for obstacles. And to solve the maze you can apply BFS .